# App not showing on PlayStore after Several Hours

Tags: android, google-play

After about 7 hours now, my app shows on the dashboard that is published and updated but i can't find in playStore. But with the direct url, i am able to see the app on the playStore. How am i having app visibility problems?

Initially, i uploaded and published it yesterday and it was showing app on playStore after some hours. I had to unpublish and make some changes and now i can't see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can take a while for new apps or updates to existing apps to propagate across all of the Play store. It can take up to 24 hours.

Comment: Is it a good idea i start sharing the direct url? Or that could cause a problem ?

Comment: @Switz Direct url to your landing page?  That's fine.

Comment: It's totally fine. Just be aware that when you publish updates to your app in the future the same issue will occur. Some users may not see the update as being available immediately. Unfortunately there's not anything you can do except wait for your update to propagate.